# Unable to implement GridView in android

Tags: android, gridview

I 'am creating an app that has

1. Coordinator layout.
2. AppBar layout (Child of Coordinator layout).
3. Collapsing Toolbar Layout (Child of AppBar layout)
4. NestedScroll View (Child of Coordinator layout).
5. GridView (Child of NestedScrollView).

**My problem**: The app crashes when I add `GridView` to it. Otherwise it works perfectly.

**What I want**: `GridView` implemented inside `NestedScrollView` so that user can scroll through all the items in the `GridView`.

my **MainActivity.java** file:

```
package com.defcomdevs.invento16;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private CollapsingToolbarLayout mcollapsingToolbar;
private NestedScrollView mnestedScrollView;
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
int backButtonCount = 0;
private Button button;
GridView mygrid;
private ImageButton imageButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)    findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
    coordinatorLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oppo));
    // drawerLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oppo));
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.setalarm);
    mcollapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    //mnestedScrollView= (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.rvToDoList);
    mcollapsingToolbar.setTitle("INVENTO '16");
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)   findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            callRegister();
        }
    });
    mygrid= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    mygrid.setAdapter(new MizAdapter(this));
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void callRegister() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registration.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    if (backButtonCount >= 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press the back button once again to close the application.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        backButtonCount++;
    }

}
  /* public void setalarm(View view){
    if(view.getId()==R.id.setalarm){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,AlarmActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}*/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.about_college) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.cse) {

    } else if (id == R.id.it) {

    } else if (id == R.id.ece) {

    } else if (id == R.id.mech) {

    } else if (id == R.id.Coding) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Coding.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.Hacking) {

    } else if (id == R.id.printing) {

    } else if (id == R.id.Big) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nand) {

    } else if (id == R.id.cryo) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
class itemName{     //Since we have to bounr the image to the item with the name and the subtitle
                    //we keep all information inside the class and deal with the class entirely
    String Iname;
    int ImageId;
    itemName(String name,int imageId){
        Iname=name;
        ImageId=imageId;
    }
}

class MizAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<itemName> items;
    Context context;

    MizAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        items=new ArrayList<itemName>();    //initialize each item with the type itemName.
        Resources res=context.getResources();
        String[] itemnames=res.getStringArray(R.array.Items);
        int[] itempics={R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn};
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            itemName names=new itemName(itemnames[i],itempics[i]);
            items.add(names);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        ImageButton myImage;
        ViewHolder(View v){
            myImage= (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row=convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder=null;
        if (row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleitem, parent, false);
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            row.getTag();
        }
        itemName temp=items.get(position);
        viewHolder.myImage.setImageResource(temp.ImageId);
        return row;
    }
}
}
```

**MainActivty.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="196dp"
            android:background="#3f51b5"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/index"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <GridView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:columnWidth="120dp"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidth">

        </GridView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have specified the imageButton that's gonna come in the `GridView` in a separate xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/hackbttn100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm new to Android. I have referred to the tutorial of the Android development series by Slidenerd. 
Please please help!!

The logcat shows the following error report:

```
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.defcomdevs.invento16, PID: 31038
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.defcomdevs.invento16.MainActivity$MizAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:226)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2283)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1044)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1335)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:434)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:607)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:674)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1155)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1394)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1042)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5892)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
10-20 22:23:24.677 31038-31038/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx: ** ERROR: PROCESS CRASHED
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx: processName: com.defcomdevs.invento16
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx: processPid: 31038
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx: shortMsg: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx: longMsg: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx: timeMillis: 1445360004687
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx: stack:
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at com.defcomdevs.invento16.MainActivity$MizAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:226)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2283)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1044)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1335)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:434)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:607)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:674)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1155)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1394)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1042)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5892)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-20 22:23:24.677 888-1437/? E/ActivityManagerServiceEx: #
```

Comment: where is your Logcat?

Comment: Should'nt a regular ScrollView work?

Comment: From what i read in developer.android site the coordinator layout should contain Nestedscrollview,recyclerview or viewgroup as it's direct child to adjust the scrolling behaviour of collapsing toolbar